# GRAVE: Allocate exception for servlet

Tags: java, aplicação-web, servlet, tomcat8

Estou recendo esse erro!
Estou usando o tomcat 8.5

Codigo

```
package br.com.controler;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class FormularioServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
              throws ServletException, IOException {
         req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/formulario.html");
    }
}
```

**hmtl**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cadastro de livro</title>
</head>
<body>

<fieldset>
     <legend>Pagamento Cartao</legend>
  <form>
        <p><label>Nome</label>
            <input type="text" />
        <p><label>Numero Cartao</label>
            <input type="text" />
        <p><label>Bandeira</label>
            <select name="Bandeira" id="Bandeiras">
                <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
                <option value="Master Card">Master Card</option>
                <option value="Elo">Elo</option>
            </select>
        <p><label>Validade</label>
            <input type="date" />
        <p><label>Codigo</label>
            <input type="text" />
        <p><label>Valor da Compra</label>
            <input type="text" />
        <p><button>Cadastrar</button>
  </form>
</fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>testecielo2</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <display-name>teste1</display-name>
    <servlet-name>form</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>br.com.controler</servlet-class> 
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>form</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/form</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**Resposta**

> set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin ADVERTÊNCIA:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:testecielo2' did not
>   find a matching property. set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.32 set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Server built:          Jun 20 2018 19:50:35 UTC set 04, 2018 9:13:51
>   PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Server number:         8.5.32.0 set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES: OS
>   Name:               Windows 10 set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES: OS
>   Version:            10.0 set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Architecture:          amd64 set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181 set 04, 2018
>   9:13:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-b13 set 04, 2018 9:13:51
>   PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES:
>   JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES:
>   CATALINA_BASE:
>   C:\Users\RC01\eclipse-workspace\testeCielo1.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES:
>   CATALINA_HOME:
>   C:\Users\RC01\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.5.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.32
>   set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Command line argument:
>   -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\RC01\eclipse-workspace\testeCielo1.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Command line argument:
>   -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\RC01\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.5.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.32
>   set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Command line argument:
>   -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\RC01\eclipse-workspace\testeCielo1.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
>   set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Command line argument:
>   -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\RC01\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.5.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.32\endorsed
>   set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
>   INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows
>   optimal performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: [C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin/server;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS
>   Code\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\RC01\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\RC01\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Docker Toolbox;C:\Users\RC01\Desktop;;.] set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read set 04,
>   2018 9:13:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read set 04,
>   2018 9:13:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Initialization processed in 1201 ms set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Starting service [Catalina] set 04, 2018 9:13:51 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32 set 04, 2018 9:13:56 PM
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars INFORMAÇÕES: At least
>   one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug
>   logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned
>   but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning
>   can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. set 04, 2018
>   9:14:00 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars INFORMAÇÕES:
>   At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable
>   debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were
>   scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during
>   scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. set 04,
>   2018 9:14:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] set 04, 2018 9:14:00 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFORMAÇÕES: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] set 04, 2018 9:14:00 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup
>   in 9117 ms set 04, 2018 9:14:04 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFORMAÇÕES: Marking
>   servlet [form] as unavailable set 04, 2018 9:14:04 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke GRAVE: Allocate
>   exception for servlet [form] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   br.com.controler  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:546)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1044)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:773)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**imagem**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro esta na configuração do ambiente: faltou a lib javax.servlet.jar e adiciona-la a Buid-Path

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]